# Create instance of a class from inside controller class javaFX Scene Builder

Tags: java

I'm new here and totally self taught.

I have a program that has various functions that change values in an array and then outputs via Midi.

Everything was going so well until i decided to learn Scene builder.
Here is a stripped down version that highlights my problem 
I have created a GUI with one button. Every time i press that button I need to increase the value of numbers greater than zero in the array by one. My initial values are

0 1 0 1

press button to increase

0 2 0 2

press button to increase

0 3 0 3

press button to increase

0 4 0 4  etc etc .

The problem is that in the controller class to access the void in the main program it needs to make an instance thus after one button push it can't get above 0 2 0 2.
I need to keep all the arrays in the main program class as that is where all the midi stuff lives and works.
I apologize for my non technical language 
Thanks for reading here are the two relevant code files

```
package zump;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Zump extends Application {

int[] myNoteArray = {0, 1, 0, 1};

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("zumpFXML.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Main");
    launch(args);
}

void octaveUp() {
    System.out.println("Octave UP");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int fa4 = myNoteArray[i];
        if (fa4 > 0 && fa4 < 4) {
            myNoteArray[i] = fa4 + 1;
        } // eo if } 
    }// eo for
    //Print Array//
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int fa6 = myNoteArray[i];
        System.out.print(fa6);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

}
```

Here is the controller

```
package zump;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class zumpFXMLController {

    @FXML // ResourceBundle that was given to the FXMLLoader
    private ResourceBundle resources;
    @FXML // URL location of the FXML file that was given to the FXMLLoader
    private URL location;
    @FXML // fx:id="button"
    private Button button; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML
    void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    }

    @FXML // This method is called by the FXMLLoader when initialization is complete
    void initialize() {
        assert button != null : "fx:id=\"button\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'zumpFXML.fxml'.";
        button.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            System.out.println("That was easy, wasn't it?");
            Zump t1 = new Zump();
            t1.octaveUp();
            // Zump.octaveUp();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be creating an instance every time the button is pressed - you should be creating it only once, and then each time the button is pressed, access that one instance.

So the creation of the instance should be outside of your event handler, but the instance that was created should be available to the event handler.

One way to do this, for example, would be to move the creation of the instance outside one level:

```
@FXML // This method is called by the FXMLLoader when initialization is complete
void initialize() {
    assert button != null : "fx:id=\"button\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'zumpFXML.fxml'.";
    final Zump t1 = new Zump();
    button.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        System.out.println("That was easy, wasn't it?");
        t1.octaveUp();
        // Zump.octaveUp();
    });
}
```

(`final` is not necessary in Java 8, but it still helps recognizing that this is a variable that's used inside of an anonymous class/lambda expression).